Что такое "комнатное лицо"?
В книге "Война и мир" появлается такое ввыражение "комнатное лицо" -- "Лицо его, бледное и забрызганное грязью, белокурое, молодое, с дырочкой на подбородке и светлыми голубыми глазами, было самое не для поля сражения, не вражеское лицо, а самое простое комнатное лицо".
Wiktionary дает толко одно значение дла "комнатный" -- https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9 ето связано з комантой.
И так я не могу понять какое это было лицо :-). Мирное, домашные, или какое другие? Ест другие значение дла слова "комнатный"?

Лицо его, бледное и забрызганное грязью, белокурое, молодое, с дырочкой на подбородке и светлыми голубыми глазами, было самое не для поля сражения, не вражеское лицо, а самое простое комнатное лицо.
Комнатное лицо — метафорическое определение. Люди с такими лицами хороши в комнатах, в гостиных, но на поле сражения они выглядят чужими, случайными.
КОМНАТНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. 1. к Комната. К-ая дверь. К-ая температура (температура жилого помещения). 2. Такой, которого держат в жилом помещении (о растении, животном). К-ые цветы. К-ая собачка.
КОМНАТА, -ы; ж. 1. Отдельное помещение в квартире, доме, отгороженное стенами, перегородками.
